# how to move in to next tab using tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I want to create functionality when user use Tab key for moving in to next tab. every tab contains some text boxes. When user in last text box of tab 1 when it press the tab key it will go into next text box of tab2. I am craeting tab using  plain htlm css and jquery. I am not using tabs functionality of jquery. the below is my html. I am creating tab using ul an li. how I move into next `li` when my tab in first text box.

**html**

```
 <ul class='tabs'>
        <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id='tab1'>
        <ul class= "set2"> 
            <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test1" /></li>
            <li>  test 2<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test2" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id='tab3'>
        <ul class= "set2"> 
            <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test3" /></li>
            <li>  test 4<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test4" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id='tab3'>
        <ul class= "set"> 
            <li>  test 5<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test5" /></li>
            <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test6" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**this is  jquery**

```
// Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
     });
  });
            </script>
```

and this css

```
    * {padding:0; margin:0;}

    html {
        background:url(/img/tiles/wood.png) 0 0 repeat;
        padding:15px 15px 0;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
    }

    p, h3 { 
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }

    div {
        padding:10px;
        width:600px;
        background:#fff;
    }

    .tabs li {
        list-style:none;
        display:inline;
    }

    .tabs a {
        padding:5px 10px;
        display:inline-block;
        background:#666;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .tabs a.active {
        background:#fff;
        color:#000;
    }
```

Comment: check for event keypress in all the tabs and find the tab keycode to do the same

Answer (score 1):

Use this javascript:

[Demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/4n5fL/4/)

```
// Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('focus', 'a', function (e) { //from click handler to focus handler
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

And this HTML:

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1' tabindex="1">Tab 1</a> <!--tabindex added so that it could be accessed by pressing tab key-->

    </li>
    <li><a href='#tab2' tabindex="2">Tab 2</a> <!--tabindex added so that it could be accessed by pressing tab key-->

    </li>
    <li><a href='#tab3' tabindex="3">Tab 3</a> <!--tabindex added so that it could be accessed by pressing tab key-->

    </li>
</ul>
<div id='tab1'>
    <ul class="set2">
        <li>test 1
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test1" />
        </li>
        <li>test 2
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test2" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='tab3'>
    <ul class="set2">
        <li>test 3
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test3" />
        </li>
        <li>test 4
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test4" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='tab3'>
    <ul class="set">
        <li>test 5
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test5" />
        </li>
        <li>test 6
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test6" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

---

## Code Explanation

### Explanation of JS:

I have changed the event handler from `click` to `focus` so that when the div would be focused the script could run rather then on clicking it.

### Explanation of HTML:

I have added `tabindex` to the tabs so that they could be accessed by using the tab key.

Comment: Just say use tabindex on elements ;) Good answer anyway.

Comment: @A1rPun No, I have changed the js aswell, instead of using `click` handler he needs to use `focus` handler. P.S if you like this answer, give it a +1 please. :)

Comment: Now it is a great answer because you explain what you did ;)

Comment: @user3149053 You saw the demonstration?